Forward dns query for LAN IP
How to forward DNS query for all users in my LAN network?
I need to forward name, for example, "g-router" or "www.g-router.com" to IP "192.168.1.111".
Probably I should change settings in dnsmasq, but I don't know how, unfortunately.

DNS "forwarding" has a very specific meaning. From your description I think you're asking how you have the names g-router and www.g-router.com map onto the IP address 192.168.1.111. (DNS mostly doesn't care about port numbers.) Is that correct?

Yes, exactly.  How do it ?

You mentioned dnsmasq. Do you already have it installed and running?

Yes, I have this running on my main router

You say you've already got dnsmasq running as a DNS server. The documentation for this tool is really quite comprehensive (see man dnsmasq or the equivalent page online) and well worth reading through. (You don't need the DHCP part if you're just considering the DNS service.)
The entry you need is an "address" (A or AAAA) record:

-A, --address=/<domain>[/<domain>...]/[<ipaddr>]
Specify an IP address to return for any host in the given domains. A (or AAAA) queries in the domains are never forwarded and always replied to with the specified IP address which may be IPv4 or IPv6. […]

For your example of g-router and www.g-router.com to map to the IP address 192.168.1.111 you need just this entry added to the configuration file, typically /etc/dnsmasq.conf:
address=/g-router/www.g-router.com/192.168.1.111

And then reload the configuration (restart the dnsmasq daemon).

I think, by looking at your answer, you will know about dnsmasq. Please look my question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/782226/638384
